# On SQL INSERT can I use the identity column for part of the insert data in another column at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, identity, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 :
Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
PK_Column1 nvarchar(50) Primary Key.

INSERT INTO Table1 (PK_Column1) VALUES ('Name'+Id)
```

Result:

```
Id  PK_Column1
1   Name1
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to manage the Id column myself for this to work?

Comment: You dont't need to insert anything for id, as it is auto-incremented.

Comment: The problem is not inserting the id, the problem is using the Id as part of the PK column on insert: is the id avaliable immediatley? Below answer: no. Insert, get the id, then update the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187342.aspx):

> After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement completes, @@IDENTITY contains the last identity value generated by the statement.

This applies to all the other identity checkers.

You should probably write a little SP to update the record immediately after your insert if this is what you need. Given that your primary_key appears to be some unusual composite of the `ID` and a `varchar`, you would also be best reviewing your data model.

It's important to note the difference with `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

Comment: Unfortunatley it is the model I have to work with (around). Thanks, I'm updating the record after insert using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), will amend the question if I encounter any problems.

Comment: Good luck mate. If you have any control over the column data types; it may also be worth managing the IDs yourself via an auto numbering table/SP that way you can do this during the insert